# Relationship between $c_0$ and $C(K)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Suppose that $K$ is an infinite compact metric space. Define $c_0=\{ (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}| \lim_n\| x_n \|=0 \}$ and $C(K)$ the set of real-valued continuous functions on $K$.

Question: Is $C(K) \subseteq c_0$? In this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-04/S0002-9939-05-08301-2/S0002-9939-05-08301-2.pdf), in the proof of Theorem $5$, there is this sentence:

> Since the spaces $C(K)$ are absolute Lipschitz retracts, there is a Lipschitz retraction from $c_0$ onto $C(K)$ which maps $0$ to $0$.

From what I understand from the statement above, it seems that $C(K)$ is a subset of $c_0$. Otherwise there won't be any retraction from $C(K)$ onto $c_0$.

Remark: A Banach space is called *absolute Lipschitz retract* if for every metric space $Y$ containing $X$, there exists a retraction $r:X \rightarrow X$ such that $r$ is also Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is included in the third line of the proof of the theorem you are interested in!

> *By a classical result of Aharoni (see Theorem 7.11, p. 176 in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545583/is-c-0-complemented-in-ck/1545886#1545886)), we know that there is a 3-Lipschitz-homeomorphism between $C(K)$ and some subset of $c_0$.*

This proof can be summarized in four steps as follows:

1. By Sobczyk's theorem, any (linear) copy of $c_0$ in $C(K)$ is 2-complemented. (See my answer in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545583/is-c-0-complemented-in-ck/1545886#1545886).)
2. By Aharoni's theorem $C(K)$ embeds into $c_0$ by a 3-Lipschitz homeomorphism (this time this map cannot be expected to be linear as there are obstacles concerning the Szlenk index) and we get actually a retraction from $c_0$ onto the range of this embedding.
3. We lift these morphisms to linear maps between the free spaces which give linear embeddings with complemented ranges.
4. We apply [the Pełczyński decomposition method](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LU3uCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&dq=Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski%20decomposition%20method&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRitfe1LDJAhXFXRQKHffKAYgQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski%20decomposition%20method&f=false) to get an isomorphism between free spaces.

Answer (score 1):

That proof starts with the sentence that $c_0$ is $2$-complemented in $C(K)$. And indeed $c_0$ is isometrically embedded into $C(K)$. This holds as $K$ is an infinite compact metric space, so has a convergent sequence (with all different terms) $x_n$ with limit $x$ (unequal to all $x_n$). Call $S = \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{x\}$. Then $C(S)$ embeds into $C(K)$ (this is due to Dugundji, I think) and there is a projection of $C(K)$ onto $C(S)$ (restriction), and $\{f \in C(S): f(x) = 0\}$ is isometric to $c_0$.

Comment: $c_0$ embeds isometrically into any $C(K)$ with $K$ infinite. Simply take a sequence of pairwise disjoint open sets, and use Urysohn's lemma to produce norm-one functions supported in these sets. The linear span of these functions is isometric to $c_0$. If $K$ is metrisable, then by Sobczyk's theorem this span is 2-complemented.